# Enterprise lib 5.0 not detecting app.config

Tags: enterprise-library

I have a Solution which contains a Web project and a Class Library project. The Class library project contains Enterprise library 5.0 and app.config. When I try to perform a Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write, I get the following exception:

> Resolution of the dependency failed,
>   type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter",
>   name = "(none)". Exception occurred
>   while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type
>   LogWriter cannot be constructed. You
>   must configure the container to supply
>   this value.
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the
>   container was:   Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter,(none)

If I move all the class files to the web project and have the Enterprise library configuration in the Web.config, everything works fine. I guess the issue is that the Enterprise library is not detecting the app.config which contains all the configuration.

Kindly help me with this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

.NET dlls don't have config files. AppDomains do. You cannot put *any* configuration in a dll's "app.config" file and expect it to get automatically picked up. This is the way .NET config files work; it's not that "entlib is not automatically detecting" it, it's doing what the .NET framework defines the behavior of config files to be.

The answer is to leave the code in the library, but put the configuration in the web app's web.config file. Then everything will just work.

There are more advanced things you can do like manually loading the config file, but they're fairly advanced and, particularly with logging, can cause admin headaches later.